# SQL SERVER - Substring

Tags: sql, get, substring

Bom dia

Senhores

Gostaria de saber como que faço pra selecionar um valor dentro de uma tabela onde ela comece com um determinado valor

Por exemplo :

**CampoEmail** 
teste@dominio.com.br 
fulano2@dominio1.com.br 
fulano2131@dominio2.com.br

Quero apenas pegar os valores do @ para frente .

Tem alguma function que faça isso ?

Answer (score 1):

para fazer isso, basta calcular a posição do `@` e do tamanho da string, segue abaixo um exemplo simples e testável:

```sql
DECLARE @email varchar(60);
SELECT @email = 'fulano2131@dominio2.com.br';
select SUBSTRING(@email, charindex('@',@email),LEN(@email))
```

Caso queira remover o `@` da resposta, basta somar 1 no charindex:

```
select SUBSTRING(@email, charindex('@',@email)+1,LEN(@email))
```

Answer (score 0):

Luiz, veja se ajuda:

```
declare @document varchar(64),  @charinicio int = 0
select @document = 'fulano@dominio.com.br';  
set @charinicio = (select  CHARINDEX('@', @document))
select SUBSTRING(@document, @charinicio+1, len(@document))
```

> Result: 'dominio.com.br'

Comment: Muito obrigado @Degas,  funcionou aqui perfeitamente  ;